# Adding class via JavaScript function based on Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add a css class to a checkbox label based on json data received via an ajax call. I can read and do necessary tasks with the data except for applying a css class to a checkbox label when the value of the list is already available. What am I missing?

When the ajax is successful, I'm calling `studatapopulate(1,app);` Following is my `js`

```
function studatapopulate(id, data) {
    var ref = data[id].ref;
    var exam = data[id].exam;

    var tutes = "";
    jQuery.each(data[id].tutedata, function (index, value) {
        tutes += '<li>'+value.subj+'</li>';
        tutes += '<ul>';
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 21; ++i) {
            tutes += '<li><label class="tutebtn" for="'+id+'_'+value.id+'_'+i+'"><input type="checkbox" id="'+id+'_'+value.id+'_'+i+'" data-subj="'+value.id+'" value="'+i+'"';

            jQuery.each(value.issuedtutes, function (indexa, valuae) {
                if (valuae == i) {
                    jQuery(this).closest('label').addClass('tutegot');
                    tutes += ' checked="checked" disabled="disabled"';
                }
            });

            tutes += '/> '+i+'</label></li>';
        }
        tutes += '</ul>';
    });
    jQuery("#tutes_"+id).append('<ul>'+tutes+'</ul>');

}
```

I tried `parent`,`parents` with no luck

Sample data for the `issuedtutes` => ["5","9","16"]

`checked="checked" disabled="disabled"` is working correctly for the above, making item 5, 9 and 16 checked and disabled.

Comment: Is it the `tutegot` class that it will not add`? If so, try add `console.log(jQuery(this))` and see if you get an object.

Comment: What is `jQuery(this)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that is correct.

Comment: @SourabhSomani I'm trying to refer to the current input element, hence referencing the parent label.

Comment: @SourabhSomani `this` in your code will not refer to the `input` from `tutes`

Comment: Could you provide **sample data** that you are passing. And also the current output of **tutes** you are getting.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I get `n.fn.init ["5"]`, `n.fn.init ["9"]` and `n.fn.init(2) ["1", "6"]`

Comment: @Sid Did my solution help you to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Do not select the closest label before appending the element in the first place.

Just do adding the **tutegot** class after you append the html element to the **tute_[id]**.

This might not be the optimal solution. But this works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
HI

<ul id="tutes_1">
</ul>


<script>

function studatapopulate(id, data) {
    var ref = data[id].ref;
    var exam = data[id].exam;

    var tutes = "";
    jQuery.each(data[id].tutedata, function (index, value) {
        tutes += '<li>'+value.subj+'</li>';
        tutes += '<ul>';
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 21; ++i) {
            tutes += '<li><label class="tutebtn" for="'+id+'_'+value.id+'_'+i+'"><input type="checkbox" id="'+id+'_'+value.id+'_'+i+'" data-subj="'+value.id+'" value="'+i+'"';
            jQuery.each(value.issuedtutes, function (indexa, valuae) {
                if (valuae == i) {
                    tutes += ' checked="checked" disabled="disabled"';
                }
            });

            tutes += '/> '+i+'</label></li>';
        }
        tutes += '</ul>';
    });
    jQuery("#tutes_"+id).append('<ul>'+tutes+'</ul>');
   $("input:checkbox:checked").parent().addClass("tutegot")
}

var a = {
 1: {
  ref: 123,
  exam: 123,
  tutedata: [
   {
       id: 1001,
    subj: 'a',
    issuedtutes: [
     "5", "9", "16"
    ],
   },
   {
       id: 1002,
    subj: 'b',
    issuedtutes: [
     "5", "9", "16"
    ],
   }
  ]
 }
};

studatapopulate (1, a);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**
 Code is optimized as suggested by @Carsten Løvbo Andersen.

Comment: Why use so much code to just add the class `tutegot` when you can use `$("input:checkbox:checked").parent().addClass("tutegot")` look here https://jsfiddle.net/4daqpo06/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks for the optimization :). It reduces helluva lines of code.